# My code has a fatal error when i'm trying to access a particle file in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, runtime-error, particles

I'm sumonning particle that i've created in a .sks file. Most of the time, particles are well sumonned but sometimes (like one out of 400) i have a fatal error.

This is the code is use to summon particle :

```
    func createParticle(touchLocation : CGPoint) {
      let particles = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle.sks")!
      let touch = CGPoint(x: touchLocation.x, y: self.view!.frame.height - touchLocation.y)
      particles.position = touch
      particles.zPosition = 1
      addChild(particles)
      particles.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0), SKAction.removeFromParent()]))

}
```

And when there is a fatal error it is at this line :

```
    let particles = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle.sks")!
```

It says " Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value ". It's maybe because he did not find the file but then the real question is **WHY** did'nt he found the file while most of the time he find it... Note : this script is executed after detecting a touch.

I tried this :

```
func createParticle(touchLocation : CGPoint) {
    for _ in 0...100 {
        let particles = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle.sks")!
        let touch = CGPoint(x: touchLocation.x, y: self.view!.frame.height - touchLocation.y)
        particles.position = touch
        particles.zPosition = 1
        addChild(particles)
        particles.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0), SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
    }
}
```

And i execute the whole script approximatively a 100 times to test if there will be a fatal error but it did not happened...

Comment: You are making two basic mistakes.  (1) Accessing the exactly same file 100 times in a for loop.  (2) Force-unwrapping an optional value.

Comment: Oh yeah, why did'nt i think of it... The solution then would be to do something like :

guard let particles = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle.sks") { else return }

Then when there is a bug and when the programm don't find the file, it will just not create any particle... Thank You !

Comment: Do not use the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileIO access is always going to be slow.  When looping really fast, you are going to run into a situation where you may be reading a file that is not already closed, and thus get a nil returned.

Instead, call your method once, and store it in a variable.

You can then copy your node, allowing you to make the 100 duplicates you need.

```
var particleNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MyParticle")!  

func createParticle(touchLocation : CGPoint) {
    let particles = particleNode.copy() as! SKEmitterNode
    let touch = CGPoint(x: touchLocation.x, y: self.view!.frame.height - touchLocation.y)
    particles.position = touch
    particles.zPosition = 1
    addChild(particles)
    particles.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0), SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
}
```

Comment: i don't need a 100 particle, the loop was just for testing but thank you I think your solutions will work for what i want to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to answer this part of the question:

> the real question is WHY did'nt he found the file

My answer assumes that the problem happens every time but only on certain builds.

If the '.sks' file is 0 bytes during the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase, then that could be the reason.

You can inspect if the file is present in the Simulator for the build that failed. Do `cd ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices` and then `find . -name MyParticle.sks`. Then do `ls -l` on the file name that is output. Is MyParticle.sks the size you expect? Is it there at all?

Comment: Sorry, i did'nt understand the first part of your answer. And i can't just wait 4 seconds after detecting touch because it need to be immediate. When you click on the screen, the programm test if it match the button position and if it match, then it increase score and generate one particle. And if the user click again it redo it. And the build phase is at the begining, this script never crash at the begening

Comment: @Titouan I misunderstood what you meant by "touch". Let me update answer.